# Content not showing in IE due to vertically aligned div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Hi i am working on a maintenance page for my website. I am using the app_offline page in asp.net MVC. I have managed to handle translations without a back end by using the browsers language settings. The issue i am having is i am using bootstrap and i have centered a jumbotron on the page to display the maintenance message, However the content does not display in IE but it works fine as always in Chrome and Firefox. I think its my css causing the issue but i am not sure it took me long enough to get the vertical center working. I have included the html and css below and a fiddle of the working page.

JSFIDDLE: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8ftbgyj/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="Logo"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
            <h1><span class="sRed">
            <ul class="text">
                <li class="en active"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Maintenance Mode</li>
                <li class="fr"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Mode maintenance</li>
                <li class="es"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Modo de mantenimiento</li>
                <li class="nl"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Maintenance Mode</li>
                <li class="pt_BR"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Modo de Manutenção</li>
                <li class="pt_PT"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Modo de Manutenção</li>
                <li class="de"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>Wartungsmodus</li>
            </ul>
        </span></h1>

        <ul class="text">
            <li class="en active">
                <h3>Site is currently undergoing scheduled maintenance. We will be back very shortly. Sorry for the inconvenience!</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="fr">
                <h3>Site est actuellement en cours de maintenance . Nous serons de retour très bientôt.</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="es">Site se encuentra actualmente en mantenimiento programado. Volveremos muy pronto.</li>
            <li class="nl">Site ondergaat momenteel gepland onderhoud . We zullen weer zeer binnenkort .</li>
            <li class="pt_BR">Site está passando por manutenção programada. Estaremos de volta em breve.</li>
            <li class="pt_PT">Site está passando por manutenção programada. Estaremos de volta em breve.</li>
            <li class="de">Site wird derzeit Wartungsarbeiten durchgeführt. Wir werden sehr bald wieder kommen.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    font-family:"Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.sRed {
    color: black;
}
u {
    color: #008854;
}
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.Logo {
    background-color: White;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #cce6da;
    border-top: 6px solid #32353E;
    height: 66px;
}
.jumbotron {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
}
li {
    display: none;
}
li.active {
    display: initial;
}
.fa-exclamation-triangle {
    color: #008854;
    padding-right: 18px;
}
```

Again thank you for any help.

Comment: which IE version your are using?

Comment: im using IE 8 and above

Answer (score 0):

IE8 not supported CSS3 and some Bootstrap Feature try to upgrade your browser to IE 9,10,11

OR also search here which feature is supported to which browser version.

http://caniuse.com/

to run this in IE8 
USE: html5shiv.js AND respond.min.js.

**HTML5 Shiv**
The HTML5 Shiv enables use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy Internet Explorer and provides basic HTML5 styling for Internet Explorer 6-9, Safari 4.x (and iPhone 3.x), and Firefox 3.x.

**Respond.min.js**
The goal of this script is to provide a fast and lightweight (3kb minified / 1kb gzipped) script to enable responsive web designs in browsers that don't support CSS3 Media Queries - in particular, Internet Explorer 8 and under.

also read this bootstrap browser support: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support